# How to pass null value in bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is a sample query that shows I'm trying to get the book called 'sql for everyone' with a begin_date '2018-02-02' where authName  is null.
This query is perfectly fine. It returns a row similar to the one in the screenshot below.

```
SELECT
  bookName,
  begin_date,
  authName
FROM bookwh
WHERE bookName = :bname
AND begin_date = :dt
AND authName IS NULL
```

[image]

My question is how can I pass null as a bind variable?
such as, and `authName = :a_null`  I should be able to pass null

Comment: What is the programming language

Comment: I think you need an indicator variable.

Answer (score 5):

NULL is a special case in a `WHERE` clause and doesn't work when testing for equality. With nulls, you can only test for `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

One way to accomplish what you want is to wrap the equality check in an nvl wrapper. The `nvl()` function takes 2 parameters. The first parameter is a value (in your case, a bind parameter) and the second value is the default value in case the first parameter is null.

```
AND authName = nvl(:your_bind_parameter, authName)
```

Another option is to use an OR statement.

```
AND (authName = :your_bind_parameter OR authName IS NULL)
```

`NVL()` a clean way to handle null bind parameters. Both of these methods have performance implications so check your explain plans.

For a more thorough explanation of your options, check out this blog on the Oracle website: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/optional-search-parameters:-getting-rid-of-those-pesky-or-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me
select * from table_name
where
((:parameter is not null and authName = :parameter) or (:parameter is null and authName is null));

Answer (score 0):

You pass null value in bind variable.

Using SQL Query to return data in table to use like this sample query.

```
select * from table_name where (authName = :parameter OR authName IS NULL)
```